# how to switch connection string using switch case and session

Tags: c#, asp.net

my application is like one application with multiple database[all databse are with same schema] i need to switch the connection on dropdown select.i am now managing the all connection string with switch case but now i need to transfer the all connection string to class[.cs] file for globally use in hole app how to do this if session is correct then how to pass string using session to class file and how to retrieve it in hole project

now my cs file is:-

```
public class connectionstr {    static string mulcon = "";
static SqlConnection myconnection = null;
public connectionstr()
{
    //      // TODO: Add constructor logic here         //
}
public static SqlConnection getconnection(string opt)
{
    if(opt=="RV001")
    {
        mulcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DUM01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
    else if(opt=="SV001")
    {
        mulcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompMasterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
    if(myconnection==null)
    {
        myconnection = new SqlConnection(mulcon);
        myconnection.Open();

    }
    return myconnection;

}

}
```

but i need to add this in one webform which have dropdown the we shift the connection on dropdown selection and also which connection is selected that that connection is applied with all project webforms

Comment: You need to rephrase question content in order to make it more understandable. Your requirement is not clear currently.

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially need is a single repository for the entire application. You have few options -

1. Singleton pattern - More details [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) - Basically you have to implement a singleton class which acts as a store for the connection string. Keep a dictionary in the singleton class. The key in the dictionary will be the user id, and the value will be the selected connectionstring. When the user selects the connectionstring, insert into the dictionary against the user. Wherever he needs a connection, use the connectionstring from the store.
2. You can do the same by storing the connectionstring in a session variable. As long the user session is valid, you can retrieve it and use it.